# Eclipse close automatically

Tags: eclipse

I,m using two eclipse in my computer. But one version automatically close frequently.I can't figure out why it is. Can anyone help me. Is it a problem to use two eclipse in same computer?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there are any error messages.

Comment: you mean  different version of eclipse you have or one version of eclipse and have 2 instance of it ?

Comment: You can run multiple instances (of the same or of different installations) at the same time if they use different workspaces. If you don't find anything in the log (see @greg-449's comment), it might also be caused by an installed plug-in. What Eclipse version are you using and what additional plug-ins have you installed?